# Which crypto-algorithem uses iOS in NSDataWritingFileProtection and what is the keysize?

Tags: encryption, mobile, ios, objective-c

I need to know the crypto algorithm and key strength of `NSDataWritingFileProtection`. I would like to know the same things for using the Keychain and `NSFileManager`.

I searched the Apple Developer references:

- [Security Services](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/Security_Overview/Security_Services/Security_Services.html)
- [`NSDataWritingOptions`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/NSDataWritingFileProtectionNone)

But found nothing specific.

The [Advanced Encryption Standard Algorithm Validation List](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/STM/cavp/documents/aes/aesval.html)
 contains multiple entries of Apple using AES 128bit-256bit but nothing in connection to keychain or `NSDataWritingOptions` or `NSFileManager`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple themselves use 256-bit AES for their apps, but you can choose from AES, RC4, or 3DES in a variety of key lengths.

See Apple's [Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Reference/certifkeytrustservices/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000157) and [Cryptographic Services Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/cryptoservices/GeneralPurposeCrypto/GeneralPurposeCrypto.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011172-CH9-SW1)